# Download pdf/word button javascript /jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, pdf, d3.js

I have data that saved in csv file. The data was used for creating some interactive graphs using d3.js and javascript. The files I have to run the graphs are some js files, css and html files. I don't need any server to run it.

Now, I want to add a download button on the page where the graphs are displayed. When user click download button, the csv will be downloaded as pdf/word file. Does anyone know how to do that? Any plugin to recommend?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You can usually set the name a file has to be downloaded in, so try changing the .csv file type to the type you need. Depending on what you use, it might work. Eg. saving a .csv as .xls makes it openable in excel. Though I havent tried a pdf this way yet.

Comment: https://github.com/rndme/download provides a function to download a string in any browser where that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you. There is an HTML5 rule called "download" that can be added to an anchor tag.

```
 <a href="documents/message.csv" target="_blank" download><button>Download</button></a>
```

In most browsers this "download" command forces the browser to open the download box. The download box itself will allow users to select their download format.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an online cloud account with any free cloud-base storage (mega.nz is good), create folders for the files you want the public to see, upload those different formatted files into its own folder > copy file link and paste it in your button code like:

```
<a href="FILE LOCATION" target="_blank" download><button>BUTTON NAME</button></a>
```

on your site, it will show a rectangled grey download button that will redirect public to the folder with all those files they can choose to download.